# get token stats

Tags: eosio.token

I found the following in the eosjs docs:

> eos.getCurrencyStats(code, symbol) ⇒ getCurrencyStatsResult

I was able to receive all stats for

> eos.getCurrencyStats('EOS', 'eosio.token')

as well as all self created tokens on my local test node. I was looking for symbols on the main net and found RIDL, POOR and WIZZ. Using their symbols just returned an empty object.
So either these tokens aren't really published yet or using 'eosio.token' is the wrong contract.

Was anybody successful getting stats for main net tokens?

Comment: `using 'eosio.token' is the wrong contract` This can be true, I think. Try deploying a contract on local and verify whether this is the reason. Meanwhile, will check for these tokens on mainnet too.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked: Using contracts from https://github.com/eoscafe/eos-airdrops

So all wallet providers need to have access to all contract names or even their own little database. Is there a package in development to get the most recent ones?

Answer (score 0):

This npm package works: [eos-token-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eos-token-info)